# Retrieving content from the _catalogs directory of a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to retrieve content from the _catalogs directory of a SharePoint site using a script. I've no idea where to start. My first thought was to use wget, but I soon discovered that the the _catalogs folder isn't available over http. As far as I can tell, it's only available in SharePoint Designer. Is there a way to retrieve this content via a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the webdav interface.

e.g. \\mysite_catalogs

Comment: That does it! Thanks! I didn't realize you could access SharePoint sites using \\. I'm a little confused though. Isn't \\ the syntax for an SMB share? I've always accessed the WebDAV interface using http://

Comment: Not sure of the details, but SharePoint implements the \\ by the WebDAV protocol